# Reboot Event time on OSX

Tags: macos

I know there are multiple ways to get last reboot time on mac but is there any way to know when the reboot event was initiated. Like on windows, we can check event log for id 1076 to get that info. Is there something similar on OSX? I tried

```
sysctl -a | grep kern.boottime
```

This gives me last reboot time but not when reboot was initiated. Also, I only care about reboot not shutdown and sysctla command returns even if there is a shutdown event.

How can I get similar info on OSX like that on Windows- Event ID : 1076?

Answer (score 1):

The command `last reboot` shows you a list with dates and times of the last few reboots.

As documented in the BSD General Commands Manual:

> The pseudo-user reboot logs in at reboots of the system, thus `last reboot` will give an indication of mean time between reboot.

Comment: last reboot on my Mac is not giving any info except wtmp begins Mon Mar 14 11:33. Thats why looking for some other resort.

Comment: Do you use cleanup or maintenance software (eg. CCleaner)? In this case it is possible that the log files are deleted so that they can not be interpreted by the `last` command.

Comment: This is my professional system so may be in the backend they do..I dont know but then assuming this use case, last reboot will fail. Any other option?